# ggplot facet_grid with colours for sign

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a facet_grid and want to colour the dots on the lines different based on the sign of a growth variable. For some reason I get 2 lines in most panels. As you can see from the chart it doesn't work correctly.

```
df2$sign <- paste(sign(df2[df2$variable %in% c('growth'), 'value']))
gg <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = date, y = value, colour = sign)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = 'free_y')
gg <- gg + scale_fill_manual(values = c('1' = "green", '-1' = "red", 'NA' = 'black'))
```

[image]

Update, the whole dput might be too much, here is a chunk

```
> dput(df2[sort(sample(1:nrow(df2), 20)), ])
structure(list(date = structure(c(113, 204, 330, 442, 764, 834, 
274, 582, 239, 316, 533, 57, 680, 715, 813, 120, 162, 260, 582, 
785), class = "Date"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
), .Label = c("x", "trline", "abovtrend", "growth", "growthpc"
), class = "factor"), value = c(13.3161181999425, 16.1064371699508, 
17.4335499999019, 15.7080705228661, 21.2452347312702, 24.1828936950835, 
15.8272720823308, 19.1001953187372, 0.716627289232031, 0.618404918297323, 
-0.219587860370801, NA, 4.20745119442357, 1.15183152074574, 0.978670728352593, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.808835828791911, 0.179073426736106), sign = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "-1", "1", "1", "NA", "1", "NA", "NA", "1", "NA", 
"1", "1", "1", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1", "1")), .Names = c("date", 
"variable", "value", "sign"), row.names = c(17L, 30L, 48L, 64L, 
110L, 120L, 160L, 204L, 275L, 286L, 317L, 369L, 458L, 463L, 477L, 
498L, 504L, 518L, 564L, 593L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: we _kinda_ need `dput()` output of a representative sample of `df2` or representative simulated data for it.

Comment: Likely culprit is that you are only using `geom_line()`. I would suggest also adding `geom_point()` and coloring that only. No need to color the entire lines differently.

Comment: Thanks for posting the data - just so you know it only has `variable = "x"` ever so the facetting won't do anything.

Comment: have sampled the snippet now

Comment: The issue you are having is not with faceting, so (in the future) it may make things easier to simplify the plot to just the issue at hand (the multiple lines)

Answer (score 0):

Like @hrbrmstr said in his comment we really need the data here to give a clear answer, but I believe you are getting the results you have because you actually haven't added any points to your plot to color. You color your lines. Is this what you wanted?

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  y1 = c(1, 2, -2, -3, 5)

)
df$color <- ifelse(is.na(df$y1), "NA",ifelse(df$y1 < 0,"-1","1"))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y1)) + geom_point(aes(color=color),size=4) + geom_line() + theme_minimal()
```

This colors points below 0 as red and above as blue. It's easy enough to change around the colors as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to color the lines, without breaking them, you need to tell `ggplot` to treat them as one group, using `group` like so (using @MikeyMike's data for simplicity):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y1, color = color, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Otherwise, it assumes that the color groups should be plotted separately. Explicitly setting `group` overrides it. You may need to change how you are calculating the sign to make sure that the line segment you want is colored, but this should give you a good start.